# `overflow-y: auto` ignoring parent's height

Tags: html, css

Why does overflow-y do nothing in the following?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid; height:100px">
    <div>2</div>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto">
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">3</div>
```

I would like the "sadfasfsda" to scroll when it outgrows the parent div, but not the "2".  I don't understand why the parent div's height property is being ignored here.

By comparison, this behaves completely differently (but not desirably either):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid; height:100px">
    <div>2</div>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto; height:100%">
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you don't have overflow on this particular div. Overflow happen only when you fix the height/width and the content appear outside of the element. Actually your content is inside; thus you have no overflow.

> CSS uses the term overflow to describe the contents of a box that
>   **extend outside one of that box’s edges** (i.e., its content edge,
>   padding edge, border edge, or margin edge). The term might be
>   interpreted as elements or features that cause this overflow, the
>   non-rectangular region occupied by these features, or, more commonly,
>   the minimal rectangle that bounds that region.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/)</sup>

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<!-- This one is having an overflow -->
<div style="border: 1px solid; height:100px;border:1px solid green">
    <div>2</div>
    <!-- This one is NOT having an overflow -->
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;border:1px solid red">
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">3</div>
```

In order to fix this you have to limit the height of the red div.

Here is an example:

```css
.green {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<div class="green" style="border: 1px solid; height:100px;border:1px solid green">
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="red" style="overflow-y: auto;border:1px solid red">
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">3</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to indicate that I don't want the red box to overflow outside the green box?

Comment: Thanks, one more question: Is it possible to make the red box fill all available space in the green box even if it does not overflow?

Comment: @asdf yes, add `flex:1` to the red box

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `overflow-y: auto` to the div in which you have set `height: 100px`

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid">1</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid; height:100px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div>2</div>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
        sadfasfsda<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid">3</div>
```

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: This results in "2" being part of the scrolled content.

Comment: let me help you

Comment: please check the snippet now, i have updated it @asdf